# Background noise generator

Tags: website-design, looking-for-a-script

I want to make a noise background. Do you have any recommendation for texture generators? I want to input color, noise density and the tile size and get a png image.

This is an example of such generator, but I want to try others:

http://www.noisetexturegenerator.com

Comment: First of all, what server-side language you need?

Comment: Python, but why does it matter?

Comment: Because you can do this also with server-side language. So if it was your goal, it matters.

Comment: When you say "noise", what do you mean? White noise, Perlin noise, simplex noise, something else?

Comment: By noise I mean rough, in contrast to solid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to create a scripted noise generator, this one looks interesting: http://www.patternify.com/

If you want a scripted noise generator, check this post: http://brunogirin.blogspot.com/2009/09/making-noise-with-imagemagick.html

ImageMagic is a tool that is already installed in many servers and can be used trough many programming languages.

Comment: Patternify looks interesting, though not sure if I can create the noise I want with it.

Comment: @grigy if you can't create the noise you want with it that's another problem and question. The imagemagick post seems to let you select a size, color, density, and file type. That answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any generators, but this is easily achieved in a graphics program like Photoshop or GIMP.

1. Create an image at your required tile size.
2. Generate some random noise.
3. Use a colorise function and/or hue/brightness editor to make it the color you like.
4. Reduce contrast to make it more subtle.

Comment: I want to make such a tile that borders and a pattern are not visible and after replication in 2D.

Comment: @grigy if you generate random noise then there is no "pattern" to it and you will not see any joins in the tiles. I'd recommend using at least a 100x100 tile.

Comment: @grigy there are generators online, there are programs such as photoshop and gimp. You can even code your own server side as Osvaldo pointed out in his answer. If you keep saying you want this and you want that. Go get help on http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/