# Client-side background noise generation script

Tags: looking-for-a-script, website-design, background-image

my question is quite similar to this one: [background noise generator](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/21742/background-noise-generator) but without having to store and transmit an image, in png, jpg, gif or even css/base64 (i.e. not server-side but client-side):

Is it possible to dynamically (client-side) generate a web page's (noisy) background image, from scripting from the same page? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Uh, looking at Stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8580541/a-way-to-create-random-noise-background-image-png-with-javascript gives this example: http://jsfiddle.net/SfzPc/14/